# I *sometimes* get the "MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as any computer signature" error

Tags: azure, get, blob, signature, labview

I'm using LabVIEW to PUT and GET data to blobs for an IoT application. I have no problem putting the data to the correct account, container, and blob, but when I try to get it, it doesn't work sometimes.
90% of the time, it all works great, but there are cases when I get this and other errors (like headers not being correct or things like that).

I've looked at the source pretty carefully and there don't seem to be any edge cases or anything that would make the code behave any differently from call to call, so I don't think it's an application problem, but I may be wrong.

This wouldn't be a problem, but when I get the MAC signature error, the function takes forever to give back a response, thus making my latencies unacceptable high. The function normally calls in 20 ms or less, but when I get this error, it can go up to 10 seconds or more (I've seen as high as 2 minutes).

There are a lot of great solutions here that solve this problem, but none that explain why it might be sporadic like I'm experiencing. Because I'm using LabVIEW, I know there aren't many users here who may be able to help, but I'm hoping I'll get lucky!

Thanks!

Comment: What library do you use for HTTP requests?

Comment: This isn't really a LabView issue. From Googling the error message, it appears you are trying to post data to Microsoft Azure. Is that correct? I'm not familiar with the HMAC signing algorithm for Azure, but the AWS algorithm requires that headers be put in canonical order; probably the same here. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key . 
If you are using debugged code, make sure your computer's clock is set correctly, as a timestamp is part of the signature. (Working 90% of the time suggests a clock issue.)